# Plastic Plugs in Surge Protectors or UPS

Tags: current, electricity, ups, surge-protection

Would plugging 4 out of 7 outlets in a surge protector or UPS with plastic “safety plugs” to keep out dust/dirt harm the product in any way?

I know that plastic is an insulator and it might affect the UPS or surge protectors amount of power it can supply by a slight margin?

Sorry for my ignorance but I am not sure how plugs would affect the product on a “slight” level and am just generally curious.

Comment: Should be fine. You should notice no difference, even if you got equipment out to try and measure the difference. That's a good idea though...I should do that.

Comment: Insulators are not affected by electricity and do not affect the electrical circuit as well. So yeah, it has no impact on power.

Comment: does the UPS have a cooling fan?

Answer (score 2):

The plastic plugs will in no way change the electrical functionality or behavior of the surge protector or UPS.

There is one thing to think about though. The plastic prongs on the plastic safety plugs are generally thicker than the metal prongs on a typical power plug. When the safety plug is inserted into an unused outlet the plastic prongs will spread the electrical contacts in the outlet more than they normally would be. For quality outlets this presents no particular problem because the range of springiness of the contacts is plenty capable of retaining its contact pressure even after the safety plug is removed. However there are the ultra low quality outlets, especially those on the cheapest plug strips *(whether they have surge protection or not)*, that can become deformed when the plastic safety plug is inserted and/or left in place for a long period of time. Outlets with deformed contacts can cause heat buildup, intermittent connections, and potential plastic melt down or even a fire.

Comment: If the contact has been loosened up by the plugs, would the power cord plugged in feel very loose and easily pop out? Also are some power cords metal contact prongs thicker than other?

Comment: @Luke - For sure there are power cords with thicker prongs than others. It is wise to evaluate the the fit of any electrical cord that you plug into any outlet. If it seems loose or ready to fall out you should not use the outlet and make a plan to get the outlet replaced as soon as feasible.

Comment: I understand, but I was referring to the plastic covers. If they were to cause damage the outlet would be loose when something were to be plugged in? Is that a valid way of seeing if the plastic covers did damage? Thanks :)

Comment: @Luke - I think the only real way to evaluate the plug to receptacle relationship is to to see if the connection seems firm and secure versus being loose and ready to fall out. A cheap outlet with plastic covers will be likely to be affected pretty much the same was as a plug with thick prongs. One main difference of course is that with the thick pronged plug it may be in use with some appliance or tool that draws a large current flow. Contact heating due to large current flow is another thing that can result in a low quality outlet's contacts losing their springiness.